# Session variable is not visible on another pages

Tags: php, session

Here is my problem: i have login page. Php code registered $_SESSION['id'] variable and on the login page all seems to be ok, but on another pages $_SESSION['id'] is not set.
Used session_start(); at all pages.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Could you provide the register code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `Print_r ($_SESSION);` to troubleshoot and see if it's really been set.

You can also post to self and make sure it's been set.

Check also if it's been unset at any moment in the code.